# Why is the identity element included in the definition of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

Why does definition of a group $G$ always include the requirement that there is identity element $e \in G$ such that for all $a \in G$, $ae=ea=a$, when I prove the existence of such an identity with only the inverse element $a$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "inverse element" if you do not already have an identity element? (I'm not saying it's not possible to have a good answer to that question, there is at least one that I know of, I'm just wondering what **your** answer is.)

Comment: You must know $e$ to say that $a \cdot a^{-1} = e$.  But are you saying that stating that $a\cdot e = e \cdot a = a$ for all $a \in G$ is not needed ?

Comment: You are right. I was doing a homework problem related to this, and I posted this question before I had to finish.

Comment: I mean, I guess you could say something like "A group is a nonempty set with a binary operation  such that, for each element $x$, there exists an element $y$ such that $xyz=yxz=zxy=zyx=z$ for all $z$" and then derive everything from that... but this would not be a good way to win friends and influence.

Comment: @MikeF .A binary associative operation.....:)

Comment: The existence of the neutral element implies that the underlying set is nonempty, which tends to be forgotten to be proved (or at least mentioned) by quite some students in their homeworks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't define the notion of an inverse element unless you know about an identity element - so you can't prove the existence of an identity element with an argument using inverses.

An argument using inverses might be useful if you want to prove that a subset of a group is a subgroup. Then knowing that the subset was closed under multiplication and contained the inverses of its elements would guarantee that it contained the identity.